# VBA check if all userform comboboxes have an option selected

Tags: vba, combobox

I have a userform with many comboboxes and an "Ok" button. What I need is that when pressing that "Ok" button, VBA to check if there's no empty comboboxes. If all comboboxes have some value selected - close the userform otherwise return a message box and clicking "Ok" on that messagebox returns me to the userform with no filled values lost.

I've tried all the methods I could think of:

```
If PackageOuterRadius = null Then

if PackageOuterRadius is nothing Then

 If PackageOuterRadius.value = 0 Then

 If IsNull(PackageOuterRadius) = True Then

 If IsNull(PackageOuterRadius.value) Then
```

What I've been trying to do is:

```
Private Sub Rigid_Filme_Ok_Button_Click()

If PackageOuterRadius.ListCount = 0 Then
MsgBox "Select a ""Package Outer Radius!"
End If
```

And absolutelly nothing actually checks if the combobox is empty and keeps returning a positive (That there's a value selected)

What could be the solution to this problem? Could someone, please, help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you have few ComboBoxes only, you may insert lines underneath the OK button to check if all the ComboBoxes are filled but if you have too many ComboBoxes on UserForm, you may achieve this with the help of a Class Module and to do so, follow these steps...

1. Insert a Class Module and rename it to `clsUserForm` and the place the following code on Class Module...

**Code for Class Module:**

```
Public WithEvents mCMB As msforms.ComboBox


Public Sub CheckComboBoxes()
Dim cCtl    As msforms.Control
Dim cntCBX  As Long
Dim cnt     As Long

For Each cCtl In frmMyUserForm.Controls
    If TypeName(cCtl) = "ComboBox" Then
        cntCBX = cntCBX + 1
        If cCtl.Value <> "" Then
            cnt = cnt + 1
        End If
    End If
Next cCtl
If cnt = cntCBX Then
    Unload frmMyUserForm
Else
    MsgBox "All the ComboBoxes are mandatory.", vbExclamation
End If

End Sub
```

2. Then place the following code on UserForm Module. The code assumes that the name of the userForm is `frmMyUserForm` and the name of the CommandButton is `cmdOK`.

**Code for UserForm Module:**

```
Dim GroupCBX() As New clsUserForm
Dim frm As New clsUserForm

Private Sub cmdOK_Click()
frm.CheckComboBoxes
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim i As Long
Dim ctl As Control

For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(ctl) = "ComboBox" Then
        i = i + 1
        ReDim Preserve GroupCBX(1 To i)
        Set GroupCBX(i).mCMB = ctl
    End If
Next ctl

End Sub
```

And you will be good to go.